# Does anyone know this skyline?

Tags: where-on-earth

Trying to figure out where this photo of my great uncle was taken and would love to see if anyone knows?

[image]

Comment: Do you know when the picture was taken, even roughly?

Answer (score 37):

Sydney, Australia.

[MLC Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25_Martin_Place) is visible in the left side. The tip of [Sydney Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Tower) is also visible behind it.

Comment: Based on the inscription on the bell, the ship seems to the cruise ship [*Sea Princess*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Dream_(1997)), which jibes with the Australian location.

Comment: And the building on the right behind the bell looks like the Australia Square tower.

Comment: @njuffa specifically it's with the ship as it's docked at Circular Quay at the overseas passenger terminal. You can see a similar view from this [google maps image](https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.8582913,151.2106855,3a,75y,168.6h,93.8t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipOAFfdmttjI98o4ne2-c-O7_dWdXZtCOMe6TaLb!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOAFfdmttjI98o4ne2-c-O7_dWdXZtCOMe6TaLb%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya183.03183-ro-0-fo100!7i8704!8i4352) taken from onboard a docked ship - a bit further back along a ship, and there are newer buildings, but it's the same view.